# Create a date validation function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have 4 inputs that have dates in my form, and I wanted to create a validation for all of those dates before submitting the form.
this is my DatetimeHelper.php

```
class DateTimeHelper
    {

    //This formats a date for insertion into the database


    public static function FormatForDB($date, $format = "m/d/Y", $if_null = "0000-00-00", $outputFormat = "date")
    {
        if (!isset($date)) {
            return $if_null;
        }

        if (trim($date) == "") {
            return $if_null;
        }

        if (trim($date) == "0000-00-00" || trim($date) == "00-00-0000") {
            return $if_null;
        }

         //var_dump(Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date));die;
        try{
            $parsedDate = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date);
            if ($outputFormat == 'date') {
                return $parsedDate->toDateString();
            } else if ($outputFormat == 'datetime') {
                return $parsedDate->toDateTimeString();
            } else if ($outputFormat == 'time') {
                return $parsedDate->toTimeString();
            }
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return $if_null;
        }

         }


    //This formats the return date from the database

public static function FormatFromDB($date, $format = "m/d/Y", $if_null = "0000-00-00")
{
    if (!isset($date)) {
        return $if_null;
    }

    if (trim($date) == "") {
        return $if_null;
    }

    if (trim($date) == "0000-00-00" || trim($date) == "00-00-0000") {
        return $if_null;
    }

    return Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $date)->format($format);
}
}
```

this is my Validator.php

```
public static function validate_date($date, $format = DATE_ATOM)
{
    try{
        $parsedDate = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        return true;
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

my controller.php

```
  $invalid_fields = [];
  $events_fields =['date_1' => 'date1',
                'date_2' => 'date2',
                'date_3' => 'date3',
                'date_4' => 'date4'];
function input_validate($request)
{

    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        switch ($key) {

            case 'date1':
                if (!$this->validate_date($value)) {
                    $this->invalid_fields[] = $this->event_fields[$key].' is not a valid date';
                }
                break;}
           case 'date2':
                if (!$this->validate_date($value)) {
                    $this->invalid_fields[] = $this->event_fields[$key].' is not a valid date';
                }
                break;}
```

This approach seems not working at all. Any help would be appreciated. I am using validate_date function in all of my controllers to validate inputs

Answer (score 0):

Why to create date validation function.
Basically you want to validate the date entered by the user , then why don't you use laravel's builtin form validator class. ([Laravel Form Validation Documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj61LOJ46LWAhUCrRQKHclXA4oQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaravel.com%2Fdocs%2F5.5%2Fvalidation&usg=AFQjCNHV-0ZbsbBBM6aIrN5TxcNB4is8ag)) which already contains the "date" type validation rules.